# File sharing doesn't work both ways - Windows 10 and 11

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-11, file-sharing

I'm trying to share folders from my desktop with windows 10(a custom build) to my laptop (a surface pro 8) with windows 11, my laptop has access to my desktop shared folders with no problems.

But, when I try to share a folder from my laptop to my desktop, no dice, it either notices my laptop but can't connect for some odd reasons (says it can't find it but lists it under network), or asks for credentials but does not work no matter what I try (entering my laptop logins, entering the added login credentials and IP from my desktop, etc…)

Here is additional information:
I use a Vpn, but no matter if it's connected, launched, or not, it does not matter

The problem started as "why can't I access my laptop Iles through my desktop with winscp, but the other way around works?"

Yes I tried most troubleshooting steps from diverse forums and sites (adding features, enabling/disabling sharing options in windows, my WiFi is set to private, I played around with the firewall,...)

I will reinitialise the laptop but I don't have faith in it working

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'd suggest [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1768525/edit) your question to add exact error messages and clarifying screenshots; they often give hints on how to overcome the problem. Have you tried whitelisting your internal network in your VPN client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that it sounds like you've already tried a number of troubleshooting techniques, you may check the network discovery settings on both your laptop and desktop. Ensure that both devices are connected to the same network and that network discovery is enabled on both of them. You may also try setting up a homegroup on one of the devices, joining it, and then adding the second device. Your antivirus programme should also be checked because it can be preventing the connection. If you can't connect, try temporarily deactivating it and see if that helps.

You might also try making sure that the workgroup names on both devices match. The workgroup name is "WORKGROUP" by default in Windows, however one of your devices may be using a different name. You may accomplish this by navigating to Control Panel > System and Security > System, then selecting "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings," and checking the information there. You might try matching the workgroup names if they are different and see if it helps.

Additionally, make sure that file and printer sharing is enabled in the network adapter settings. You may do this by selecting Properties from the context menu when you right-click on your network adapter after navigating to Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings. Check to see if "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a trouble sharing in win11 as the source on lan sharing and it took me a long time to figure it out. This is for sharing using MicrosoftAccounts which are the online login accounts.

The symptoms I had were similar where you could see the computer via network discovery but you couldn't log into the machine and it kept showing the login dialog saying you the user name and password were wrong.

In my case, the fix was to make sure that you login to the windows 11 box where you want to share from using your username and password. There is a win11 feature that is new which forces using Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts. IF this is in place, you only ever login via PIN.

I think what is happening is that somehow the logged in user isn't a user/pwd entity and it uses a different auth method to login. What happens is from any other machine you are logged in using the MicrosoftAccount, it tries to use user/pwd to auth and it fails because the win11 share you are trying to access only has this MicrosoftAccount that is using the windows hello to login.

To Fix:

1. On the win11 machine where you are trying to share from, uncheck the setting
   "For Improved Security, only allow Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts on this device (Recommended)"
2. Login using your password. You can do this by going back to lock screen and selecting login using other method.
3. This should tie your MicrosoftAccount on the win11 source machine to your user/pwd.

Other settings to verify for sharing:

1. In your wi-fi or ethernet settings, your local connection is set to the private network under network profile type.
2. Under Advanced sharing settings->private networks, network discovery:ON, File and printer sharing: ON
3. Under Advanced sharing settings->All networks, Password protected sharing: ON
4. I don't use the sharing wizard, so I disable it. This setting is under the folder options menu in the File Explorer window->options [folder options]->View->Advanced Settings->Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended): uncheck this option. This may cause your machine to automatically share the users folder for some reason which is odd fyi.

After all this you should be able to ensure your online MicrosoftAccount from the source machine and target machine should match up correctly. You may have to ensure you do this on both machines. I haven't tested that out if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I share folders on all my Windows 11 (real machines) and Windows 10 (Virtual machines) so File and Folder sharing works.

**Things to consider (especially with different operating systems and different computers).**

1. Ensure Network Discover and File and Print sharing are both selected on all computers. Restart any device where you change these settings.
2. Ensure Password Protected Sharing is ON.
3. Temporarily disable VPN while you are working.
4. You said Wireless was Private, but do check.

**Additional things to consider:**

1. Map folders by IP address or else fill out the HOSTS file to have Machine name / IP address relationship. HOSTS is in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
2. Make sure the folder on a machine that you wish to share is permitted to the username on the machine asking to share. There are various ways to do this, but make sure folders are shared.

Test this as follows: From a command prompt, NET USE T: \IP_of_other_computer\Folder.   Authenticate.  Do you succeed or do you get an error. If so what error.

3. There are still public folders but Homegroup was removed with Windows 10 V1803.  I suggest using standard sharing as in (2) just above.  Make sure all computers are in the same workgroup for standard sharing. This is pretty much default now.

When all is complete, remember to restart.